# Shared preferences null pointer exception on Activity close

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-sharedpreferences

I have the following code:

```
 public void refresh(){
        View rootView=getView();
        final SharedPreferences pref = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFav", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        Map<String,?> entries = pref.getAll();
        final Set<String> keys = entries.keySet();}
```

This function is inside a fragment and I am calling it from Activity as follows:-

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        FavLegislator fav =new FavLegislator();
        if(frag.equals("true"))
            fav.refresh();
        finish();
    }
```

The shared preferences might have changed in the Activity.
I just want an updated list of preferences when the Activity closes.

I am getting the following error on the back button press of Activity:

```
11-27 10:06:24.126 31645-31645/com.app.congress.congressapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.congress.congressapp, PID: 31645
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
  at com.app.congress.congressapp.FavLegislator.refresh(FavLegislator.java:85)
  at com.app.congress.congressapp.legislator_info.onBackPressed(legislator_info.java:466)
  at com.app.congress.congressapp.legislator_info.onOptionsItemSelected(legislator_info.java:454)
  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2912)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:147)
  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
  at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:194)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Can some one please let me know why I am getting the above error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`super.onBackPressed();` call will destroy/finish your activity and you can no longer use any object belong to this activity so simply move this call at the end and there is no need to call `finish()`

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        FavLegislator fav =new FavLegislator();
        if(frag.equals("true"))
            fav.refresh();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

change this

```
 final SharedPreferences pref = this.getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFav", 0);
```

to this

```
final SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyFav", 0);
```

Note : Better option is to create a utility class with a static method which will save your preference data so just pass the context and data to utility class and save it to preference

```
public class Util {

    public static void saveData(Context context,int i ){
      // your preference code , change parameters accordingly 
    }
}
```

from your activity call it like

```
 Util.saveData(this,5);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: @Anirban try update , you should use `getActivity()` function to retrieve the context of attach activity

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `new FavLegislator()` and expect it to have a Context.

That appears to be an Activity or a Fragment class. When you make a `new` one, the Context is not attached, so `getContext()` returns null.

If you're trying to refresh some other view when you return to it, use the `onResume`  method